# How should I handle a client who is asking me to copy?

Tags: client-relations, ethics

A company has approached me to design t-shirts. They want me to incorporate some famous band's picture as well as their logo...but I know they are asking me to copy.

If you have ever faced a similar issues, what was your approach? 
How would you deal with the client?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it involves legal issues. Please edit your question to focus on alternative approaches or ethics.

Comment: In most countries, it is illegal to use a company logo/brand on a t-shirt without permission. Not only copyright violation, but also possibly trademark violation. The products could even be viewed as counterfeit goods.  If agree to do it, then yes, you could be held responsible.

Comment: i dont understand... should i delete this question?

Comment: @suraiyaabedin- don't delete a question that someone has already answered.  The question is closed anyway because legal questions are generally off-topic here. Don't worry about it. You haven't done anything wrong. If you want you could instead edit your question so it's about the ethics of copying - that way it would be on-topic, and if enough people agree it could be re-opened.

Comment: okay. thank you. I actually decided to say NO to that designer. all I need was moral support and guidance. user287001 and you showed me the right path.. that is all i asked for. I believe seniors can help juniors with their experience. am gonna edit it. Thank you again.

Comment: With respect to US laws.. changing the color of something is **never** enough. There's **no such thing** as "change it by x amount and it's okay". If the original is discernible in any way, it is probably an infringement.

Comment: Thank you @Scott.  .. . :(   didnt even imagine something would happen like this...  CLOSED QUESTION!!  to get rid of this had to edit it. wish you saw the real one :(

Comment: I can see all your question edits, Suraiya. Without *written permission* from the companies I would refuse the work. Of course, there are some things like event sponsorship where companies *expect* to see their logos on T-shirts.. so every situation can be different. And I clearly don't know the *entire* situation.

Comment: I rolled back the question to a previous state and attempted an edit to avoid legal advice. Suraiya, please let me know if this is suitable for you.

Comment: i dont have ny problem with this one.  Thankyou. @curious

Comment: @Scott Yes it helps...  Thank you so much for introducing this post :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can happen that you live in a place where western copyright laws are not respected and companies such as Nike or Coca Cola simply have no power to collect their money from individuals. The business goes well as long as everyone in the local marketing and law enforcement system get his slice.

But that doesn't make unauthorized use of copied stuff legal if copyright laws exist. My approach is: I do not make unauthorized copies nor take part such activities for ex. by providing technical help. Even in case your client says or writes "I take the responsibility" it doesn't make you innocent if there's no legal authorization. In addition by making illegal copies you have prepared a tool for those who need something to persuade you to make more illegal copies.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your insights <3